# SELECT WITH LEFT JOIN AND WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables: Users{username, UserID} AND Prizes{UserID, prize, status}

I want to select all the users *(from Users Left Join Prizes)* except the users who has 'status = dead' in the Prizes table

Comment: Are you using mysql *and* sql-server?

Comment: Why would you need sample data to answer this?

Comment: @kekekela, I suppose you are right.  It is just an involuntary reflex to a question that doesn't show effort...

Comment: No need to show effort with questions like this. SO's got plenty of rep-hungry contributors ;-)

Comment: @mjv *rep-hungry contributors* probably is not a good term. Are you saying that question like this does not deserve to get an answer? I do answer all questions here as long as I understand and able support it. For me, I call it *charity* -- sharing of one's knowledge (*with or without expecting something in return*). `:)`

Comment: @JW apologies for the barb. I understand _charity_ and practice it myself, occasionally, on similar questions!  In truth, I feel rather `ambivalent` about such questions, particularly when they show so little effort on the part of person asking them. So, am I suggesting that such questions do not deserve an answer? I'm unsure of the best  way of using these questions to make SO a better place: Waiting and letting people with low rep respond? Encouraging OP to improve Q? Finding duplicates on SO? or Providing an excellent answer like yours with pointers to resources for learning more... (btw+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need here is `INNER JOIN` because you only want to search fors user having status not equal to `dead`.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    Users a
        INNER JOIN Prizes b
            ON a.userID = b.UserID
WHERE   b.status <> 'dead'
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    Users a
        LEFT JOIN Prizes b
            ON a.userID = b.UserID
WHERE   b.UserID IS NULL OR b.status <> 'dead'
```

Comment: No I want to select the user even if he doesn't have a prize record at all.
but if he does have a prize then apply a condition if status <> Dead

NOTE: maybe the status dead is confusing u (it is in the prize table) means the prize could be dead not the user! :P

Comment: @MahmoudZalt how about the updated answer? or see the demo here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d582/1

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort you made to answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this;

```
select u.* 
from users as u 
left join prizes as p 
on u.userid = p.userid 
where p.status <>'dead';
```

Thanks